# Click triggered after sorting sortable jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, safari, click, jquery-ui-sortable

This problem occurs on Safari. I don't get the problem on IE (which is a first).

I have a sortable:

```
<ul id='srt'>
    <li><a class='url' href='http://www.test.com'>test</a></li>
    <li><a class='url' href='http://www.test1com'>test1</a></li>
    <li><a class='url' href='http://www.test2com'>test2</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the following script:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#srt").sortable();

    $(".url").click( test );
});

function test() {
    $(this).text( "done" );
    return false;
}>
```

Clicking a link will change the text to 'done', but dragging it will also change the text to 'done'. But I don't want to click on the link at the end of a sort.

Like I said: IE is running the function like it should, it sorts the link and doesn't trigger the bound click-function, but Safari does trigger the click...

How can I prevent this from happening?

Edit: I created a [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcrXL/) for this so you can try it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I'm having the same problem in my current project, and i really don't have a clue since at the beginning was working properly, but after some change in code it stopped to work. the problem is that i made a lot of changes and i can't imagine which create the problem

Hwr in you case is simpler luckily. You should never pass event handler like this in jquery. Use this syntax:

```
$(".url").click( function(){
    test();
});
```

This works!

EDIT: 
My apologies, it still trigger the handler when sorting. Two are the solutions!

The best one:

```
$("#srt").sortable({ helper: 'clone' });
$(".url").click( function() { $(this).text( "done" ); } );
```

Using helper: 'clone' option avoid the plugin to run the handlers on the elements. (note that i included the test() body into the anonymous function, otherwise you would not be able to use "this")

Uglier one and that cause problems with event bubbling:

```
$("#srt").sortable();

$(".url").live('click', function() { $(this).text( "done" ); } );
```

This is just for teaching reasons! since the live() events are not in the elements itself, they don't get triggered by sortable!

Comment: I tried this, but it kills the click-function alltogether. check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aw2wD/

Comment: yes i'm sorry, because you pass the test() function and then use $(this) into that function; but then $(this) doesn't point anymore to the DOM element, but to the function itself! Hwr I found another and more elegant solution for our problem! Check the update!

Comment: I ran into a similar situation and using helper 'clone' fixed the issue.